# Code stops after inputting double vector and not running the inputs for string vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I'm working through the book "Programming Principles and Practice using C++", and I'm on the vectors part. I want to know why my code wont run the string vector input part unless I erase the double vector input part.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


int main()
{
    std::vector<double> temps(5);
    std::vector<std::string> maths;
    std::string g;

    for (double temp; std::cin >> temp;)
    {
        temps.push_back(temp);
    }
    //Mean temps
    double sum = 0;
    for (double x : temps)
        sum = sum + x;
    
    //Median temps
    std::sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
    std::cout << temps.size() << std::endl;
    
    //Sort and Print
    for (int y = 0; y < temps.size(); y++) 
    {
        std::sort(temps.begin(), temps.end());
        std::cout << " " << temps[y];
    }
    
    //String Test
    for (g; std::cin >> g;)
    {
        maths.push_back(g);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < maths.size(); y++)
    {
        std::sort(maths.begin(), maths.end());
        std::cout << " " << maths[y];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You create a vector with `5` elements. Then you push back new elements, *adding* to the already existing elements.

Comment: Also, the only way to stop inputting the values for `temps` is to either input something which isn't` a valid `double` or to use the end-of-file key sequence. Both of these will set the input stream in a failed state that you must clear before being able to input anything more.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude wow thanks so much. i just tried cin.clear() and it worked. now i get it. thanks alot man.